# Canvas repeat a svg or rect path

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to make this: [bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0gqZ.png)
I tried with making a single rect but I don't know how to repeat it along the x.
I tried repeating a image (svg) but it doesn't work too.
I tried with background repeat in a div but the result is everytime the same: blank.
I'd like to make it in canvas.
This is my code:

```
    const canvas = document.getElementById('barre');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image();
img.src = '../img/barre.svg';
img.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    const ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat-x');
    ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assigning a fillStyle to a canvas you are really just doing one thing: determining a property. At this point you are not actually drawing anything yet. This is done using the appropriate drawing methods. In your case the `fillRect()` method would be a perfect fit. As the name implies, it draws a filled rectangle. It takes four parameters for it's position and the dimensions.

Here's an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('barre');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat-x');
  ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
});
img.src = 'https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://picsum.photos/id/237/20/30';
```

```html
<canvas id="barre"></canvas>
```